# Calling ajax functions on load and onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

Suppose there are 2 ajax functions f1 and f2 containing a for loop with 10 iterations and I want to call f1 onload and while f1 is executing at the same time I want to call f2 on a button click so that both functions will be dispalyed simultaneously.Both the functions contain an alert msg in the for loop and both functions are same just names are different.

Can we do this?
If yes how?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes my friend, you can. But first, [show us what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) so far.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and google these terms _"JavaScript Single threaded simultaneous" and you'll probably have your answer already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can do this by calling 2nd function in onload i.e

```
  window.onload=function()
   {
      f1()('onload');    //call 1 
      f2(); 
    }
```